# What is difference between ":" and ">" characters for printing the data in JsRender template?

Tags: template-engine, jsrender

What is difference between ":" and ">" characters for printing the data in JsRender template?

```
<div>{{:Name}}</div>
```

VS

```
<div>{{>Name}}</div>
```

I would appreciate for your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.jsviews.com/#jsrtags):

`{{:Name}}` Evaluates the data-path or expression

`{{>Name}}` Gets the **HTML-encoded** value of the data path or expression, and inserts it into the rendered output

#### When JSON data is:

```
{Name: "Boris <b>Moore</b>"}
```

#### results are:

- {{:Name}} 
  returns: Boris **Moore**
- {{>Name}} 
  returns: `Boris <b>Moore</b>`

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is here:

http://www.jsviews.com/#jsrtags

http://www.jsviews.com/#assigntag

http://www.jsviews.com/#htmltag

And there is a sample here: http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/converters.

And this sample covers both JsRender and JsViews converters, including 2-way converters, but also refers to the HTML encoding converter used in `{{> ...}}`:

http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/form-els/converters

It's worth exploring the rest of the documentation too. It should make it a lot easier to figure things out!